# What is the size of a Look-Up Table?

Tags: fpga

I am working on Basys-3 board, and I need to estimate the area used by my VHDL design. It is composed of 40 LUT, so I'd like to know if it's possible to know what is the area of a LUT ?

Thank you !

Comment: Does your knowledge that it takes 40 LUTs come from synthesis reports or did you write code containing 40 look up tables?

Comment: It comes from synthesis and implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The LUT **is** a unit of area used in FPGA's.

An FPGA is comprised of (or has/contains) a total of X LUTs. (The value of X differs from chip to chip.)

Look up how many LUTs your FPGA has. 
Thus you are using 40/X percent (of LUTs) of the FPGA.

Alongside the LUT an FPGA has other basic resource e.g. registers. Most designs use more LUTs then registers. (That is mostly you run out of LUTs, before you run our of registers) Therefore the LUT usage is often the indicator how full your FPGA is .

Comment: Ok, but in some tech reports, when people talk about their hardware implementation of an algorithm, they write the results in $ µm^2 $, so I just wanted to know if some knew the size of a LUT in order to establish a parallel.

Comment: @Cedric square micrometers are only relevant for ASIC designs, not for FPGAs.

Comment: Ok thank you, I didn't know that ! This was the answer I needed then.